# Installing mongoDB on Win32

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install mongoDB on my wamp, and it just don't work. I've read all the related questions here, but my problem is once I open mongod.exe it gets stuck on the message:

> [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
>   [websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28017

I've disabled all my firewalls and still nothing seems to happen. What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Did you tried connect to mongodb through mongovue? -> http://blog.mongovue.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's stuck.  It looks like it's actively listening for connections.  (At least, based on the information you've provided.)  Can you connect to it?

For example, what happens when you point your web browser to http://localhost:28017 or when you try to connect to the database from (I'm assuming) your code?

Comment: it shows a log with stats of the mongo.. but I don't see any file installed on data/db/ and if I try to open monog.exe (the shell js client) it closes almost immediately after saying it tries to connect to test db..

Comment: also, when i try to run it through the cmd it says 'can not conenct to server at 127.0.0.1 <anon>:1154

Comment: The way I got this to work is by starting it as a service. Then you don't need to leave the CMD prompt open. Check out [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) where it says "Install and Run the MongoDB Service"